# Accessing Elements in a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, warning-messages, string-manipulation, partitions

I have nested list of the form: (which I **don't want to flatten** :) )

```
lol = {{"hello", "bye", "bye", "Hello"}}
```

How do I access the individual elements? Based on a normal list the syntax would be:

```
lol[[2]] #gives an error saying that it part does not exist of this list
```

How does ***part*** work for the nested list?

Comment: To clarify, part 1 of your expression is {"hello", "bye", "bye", "Hello"}, and so to get “bye” you need to take part 2 of part .

Answer (score 2):

The code would be:

```
lol[[1]][[2]]
```

Comment: Lol[[1,1;;2]] for hello and bye